# Django ManyToMany Equality

Tags: python, django

I have a model, `Entry.` Of particular note is its `addTags` function which adds a tag to an instance of `Entry` and saves it. Here is the full code for the class:

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    text = models.TextField()

    def getAllTags(self):
        '''
        Returns all tags applied to a given entry
        '''
        return self.tags.all()

    def addTag(self, tagName):
        '''
        Add a tag to an entry. If tag does not exist, create it. If tag has
        already been added, do nothing.
        '''
        try:
            tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tagName)
            return tag
        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
            tag = self.tags.create(name=tagName)
            self.save()
            return tag
```

The weird thing is, when I test the addTag function with the following code (entry1 was created earlier and is a valid Entry object):

```
    tag1 = entry1.addTag("testtag2")
    tag2 = entry1.addTag("testtag2")
    tag3 = entry1.addTag("testtag3")
    tagList = [tag1, tag2, tag3]
    for listTag, objTag in zip(tagList, entry1.tags.all()):
        print "%s: %s" % (listTag, objTag)
    self.assertEqual(entry1.tags.all(), tagList)
```

I get the following assertion error:

```
AssertionError: [<Tag: testtag>, <Tag: testtag2>, <Tag: testtag3>] != [<Tag: testtag>, <Tag: testtag2>, <Tag: testtag3>]
```

Yet the print statement within the code above gives me the following:

```
testtag: testtag
testtag2: testtag2
testtag3: testtag3
```

Indicating that the tags have been created as expected. It seems as though different memory locations of each tag object has been created, but I don't see how this could have been the case. Thoughts?

Comment: just a hint: you can use `Tag.objects.get_or_create` instead of this try/except block

Comment: How do you not see how this could have been the case? Django returns new instances of a model with every queryset.

Comment: @Fernando: Awesome. I expected the kind folks over at Django may have anticipated such a situation and provided code for it.

Comment: If you need an orm that returns the same instances, have a look at storm: https://storm.canonical.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.assertEqual(list(entry1.tags.all()), tagList)
```

entry1.tags.all() is a queryset which doesn't override the __eq__ method, and so compares to other objects by it's id (memory location). If you want to compare the objects returned by it to the objects in tagList, you have to evaluate the queryset first, by calling list on it.

The instances of Entry in list(entry1.tags.all()) are not the same ones as in tagList. That doesn't change both lists being equal because Entry instances do have an overridden __eq__ method and are compared by their pk.

EDIT:

When comparing a QuerySet against a list

```
entry1.tags.all() == tagList
```

you are not comparing the instances returned by it because a Queryset doesn't have the __eq__ method overridden and thus can't be compared to a list.

Two lists however can be compared. All instances in the lists are compared pairwise, and because their __eq__ provides a means other than id-comparison (it tests for pk-equality) they compare the same.

Comment: This works, but could you explain to me how calling `list` on a query set changes the way the objects are evaluated against other objects (i.e., the eq method).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to refactor your code:

```
    class Entry(models.Model):

        title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User)
        pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
        text = models.TextField()

        def getAllTags(self):
            '''
            Returns all tags applied to a given entry
            '''
            return self.tags.all()

        def addTag(self, tagName):
            '''
            Add a tag to an entry. If tag does not exist, create it. If tag has
            already been added, do nothing.
            '''
            tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tagName)
            self.tags.add(tag)
            self.save()
```

Also, in your tests you have to compare two lists:

```
self.assertEqual(list(entry1.tags.all()), tagList)
```